# antMatchers hasRole throwing 403 access denied using spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, access-denied, spring-cloud-gateway

Initially I'm using zuul for gateway operations, now migrated to spring cloud gateway. After migrating getting access denied error with the below code.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    DelegatingServerLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new DelegatingServerLogoutHandler(
            new CsrfServerLogoutHandler(csrfTokenRepository()),
            new SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler(),
            new WebSessionServerLogoutHandler(),
            new HeaderWriterServerLogoutHandler(new ClearSiteDataServerHttpHeadersWriter(ClearSiteDataServerHttpHeadersWriter.Directive.ALL))
    );

    http
            .oauth2Login().and()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/somePath/**").hasRole("SuperAdmin")
            .pathMatchers("/somePathSquare/**").hasRole("SuperAdmin")
            .pathMatchers("/somePathCube/**").hasRole("SuperAdmin")
            .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(createDefaultRequestMacher()).and()

            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())) 
            .addFilterAfter(csrfFilter,  SecurityWebFiltersOrder.CSRF) 
            .logout()
            .logoutHandler(logoutHandler)
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
            .and()
            .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll()
    ;

    return http.build();
}
```

Also tried changing the `hasRole("SuperAdmin") to hasRole("ROLE_SuperAdmin") & hasAuthority("SuperAdmin") & hasAuthority("ROLE_SuperAdmin")`.
Getting same error access denied in all the cases.

Can anyone share your thoughts and workarounds on how to fix this?